# Evitar que se repitan los numeros en una matriz

Tags: c#, matrices

Tengo un algoritmo donde lleno una matriz de 10 x 10. Deseo que al momento de imprimir la matriz , ningún número se repita.

Este es mi código:

```
int posi = 0, posj = 0, mayor = 0;//declaracion de variables para la posicion y el numero mayor

            Console.WriteLine("Matriz de 10*10\n");

            int[,] matriz = new int[10, 10];  //Creacion de la matriz de 10*10 (10filas, 10 columnas)
            Random aleatorio = new Random();//declaracion del random para llenar la matriz 

            //se recorre la matriz para asignar los valores

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {

                       matriz[i,j]=aleatorio.Next(0, 100);

                    //matriz[i, j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
                }


            // se recorre nuevamente para leer sus valores y validar cual es mayor y capturar su respectiva posicion
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        if (matriz[i, j] > mayor)//si matriz en la posicion i,j es > mayor
                        {
                            mayor = matriz[i, j]; // a mayor -> el valor que hay en la posicion i, j
                            posi = i; // a la posicion i -> i
                            posj = j;// a la posicion j -> j
                        }
                        //imprimir matriz  
                        Console.Write(matriz[i, j].ToString() + " ");
                    }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            //impresion del numero mayor y su posicion.
            Console.WriteLine("El numero mayor es:{0} y esta en la posicion {1},{2}", mayor.ToString(), posi.ToString(), posj.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cada vez que creas un número con aleatorio.Next tienes que recorrer la matriz para comprobar si está o no y si está tienes que generar otro hasta que no lo encuentre y lo pueda insertar. La quieres rellenar con valores de 0 a 99?

Comment: Hola jorge. tu pregunta fue reportada como duplicada, porque hiciste la misma y tiene respuestas validas. Y sobre todo tiene una respuesta aceptada. Si las respuesta no te satisfacieron, por favor aclara en ellas que falto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a rellenar una matriz con valores de 0 a 99 lo puedes hacer así (yo lo he hecho en una 5x5). Sólo haces el bucle para rellenar la matriz.

```
int [,] matriz = new int[5,5];
int [] arrayValores = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24};

List<int> valores = arrayValores.ToList();

Random r = new Random();

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        int indValor = r.Next(0,valores.Count);
        matriz[i,j] = valores.ElementAt(indValor);

        valores.RemoveAt(indValor);
    }
}
```

Si sabes que valores vas a introducir, para sacar el índice del valor máximo con un if cuando "sacas" el valor de la lista ya lo tienes.

Comment: Pablo muchas gracias, pero la idea es aleatoriamente , y hacer que el mismo sistema los inserte sin duplicarlos

Answer (score 1):

Una forma muy eficiente de evitar los duplicados consiste en generar un `HashSet` primero (el cual ya se ocupa de los duplicados) y luego rellenar tu matriz con los valores tomados de ahi.

Luego puedes usar `Buffer.BlockCopy` para darle la forma de matriz.

y finalmente puedes buscar el maximo como ya lo estas haciendo

```
// aqui modifique para tomar m y n de variables.
int m = 10;
int n = 10;

// generar random values, count = 10x10 (columnas x filas) = 100
HashSet<int> candidates = new HashSet<int>();
while (candidates.Count < (m*n)) 
{
    // no permite dups
    candidates.Add(aleatorio.Next(0, 100));
}

// luego le das la forma de matrix
int[,] matriz = new int[m, n];
Buffer.BlockCopy(candidates, 0, matriz, 0, num.Length * sizeof(int));

// resto del programa aqui
```